# Google Maps API v3 addDomListener method questions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

With regard to the sparse documentation found at:
[MapsEventListener object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapsEventListener)

When I use the following:

```
google.maps.addDomListener(div, 'click', function (evt) {  alert( evt.latLng.toString(); ) } );
```

I get a debugger error stating there is no such property "latLng".

However, the "MouseEvent object specification" within the same google document above states that:

> Properties
>   latLng
>   Type:  LatLng
>   The latitude/longitude that was below the cursor when the event occurred.

So is the object passed by the 'click' event NOT a MouseEvent object as described in the documentation??? (it appears not) and if not, what exactly is the object (and its properties, etc.) and where the h*** is it documented?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the `latLng` from the `div`'s click event. Your code will work fine if you attached the event listener to the `map` instead of `div`.

`div` click will fire a normal DOM event and hence there will be no `latLng` associated with it.

Use the following to get `latLng` from `map`'s click event:

```
 map.addListener('click', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.latLng);
  });
```

Comment: After examining the object in the debugger, the google.maps.addDomListener method passes a PointerEvent object to the handler -- which of course does not contain the latLng property (of course, this is NOT mentioned in the documentation).   Also, I need the listener to be attached to the div because it is part of an overlayView (which I did not mention initially, because I was just trying to figure out what addDomListener passes).  Anyway, thank-you for the reply.